# Protractor - check if element is present and either stop test or continue

Tags: protractor, automated-tests

I have a Protractor test that pulls various values from the UI and stores them as variables for comparison with values from a different database.

Now this test needs to run against multiple sites BUT of the 25 maximum data points recorded, some sites only have 22.

Clearly the test fails on those "22" sites since the elements are not present.

What I want to achieve is where there's a "22" site, the tests against the not present elements are ignored and the test proceeds to the end. Conveniently, the "missing" elements are the last ones in the spec.

Crudely speaking...

```
if element-y is not present end test or if element-y is present continue
```

Grateful if anyone could advise.

Thanks @sergey. I've modified your example as below....

```
 if (!(await element(by.xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div/section[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/div/span')).isPresent())) {
console.warn ('Functions are not present, closing the session')
await browser.close()
```

I get this error:

```
if (!(await element(by.xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/main/div/div/section[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/div/span')).isPresent())) {
        ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I've tried using a 'var' instead of the actual element, but get the same result.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

well the best option that I recall is still pretty dirty... you can do something like this

```
if (!(await element.isPresent())) {
  console.warn('Element not present, closing the session')
  await browser.close()
}
```

And then the rest of test cases will fail as `session not found` or similar error

The reason you can't do anything better because in protractor you can't do conditional test cases based on a Promise-like condition, if that makes sense...